# ffmpeg stream replication of multiple sources to multiple destinations

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm looking to replicate multiple streams from a single source, to multiple destinations. So for instance 12 streams with a dest of 1.1.1.1:1000-1011 being reflected to two destinations @ 2.2.2.2:1000-1011 and 3.3.3.3:1000-1011

I don't want any stream processing, no modification, just using -vcodec / -acodec. Receiving MPEG-TS and reflecting MPEG-TS at the same bitrate.

How would I run this with FFMPEG? Trying to read the documentation but it's not quite clear on how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'll need many many map statements.

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i protocol://1.1.1.1:1000
       -i protocol://1.1.1.1:1001
       -i protocol://1.1.1.1:1002
       ...
       -i protocol://1.1.1.1:1011
-map 0 -c copy -f tee "[f=mpegts]protocol://2.2.2.2:1000|[f=mpegts]protocol://3.3.3.3:1000"
-map 1 -c copy -f tee "[f=mpegts]protocol://2.2.2.2:1001|[f=mpegts]protocol://3.3.3.3:1001"
...
-map 11 -c copy -f tee "[f=mpegts]protocol://2.2.2.2:1011|[f=mpegts]protocol://3.3.3.3:1011"
```

I've used the tee muxer to cut in half required output strings.